# Cannot get response from getStateByPartialCompositeKey

Tags: javascript, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I cannot obtain a response from the `getStateByPartialCompositeKey` method. I can use `putState` and `getState` just fine, but cannot use `getStateByPartialCompositeKey`. I'm using NodeJS fabric-contract-api version of Fabric's chaincode.

For the development, I used [this commercial-paper example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/a3d26a136d14d89d838a2dfc2410bf9c355c3ab1/commercial-paper/organization/digibank/contract). This example uses the test-network environment, which is working just fine.

[This implementation](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/a3d26a136d14d89d838a2dfc2410bf9c355c3ab1/commercial-paper/organization/digibank/contract/ledger-api) offers some ledger API utility classes that I'm using also to interact with the ledger. It has two classes, `state.js` and `stateList.js` I added a method to stateliest called `getAllStatesFromPartialCompositeKey` to try and use `getStateByPartialCompositeKey` method.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "informed-consent-form-contract",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "description": "Papernet Contract",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8",
    "npm": ">=5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "nyc mocha test --recursive",
    "start": "fabric-chaincode-node start",
    "mocha": "mocha test --recursive"
  },
  "engineStrict": true,
  "author": "hyperledger",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "fabric-contract-api": "^2.0.0",
    "fabric-shim": "^2.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "nyc": "^12.0.2",
    "sinon": "^6.0.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "nyc": {
    "exclude": [
      "coverage/**",
      "test/**"
    ],
    "reporter": [
      "text-summary",
      "html"
    ],
    "all": true,
    "check-coverage": true,
    "statements": 100,
    "branches": 100,
    "functions": 100,
    "lines": 100
  }
}
```

Contract.js snippet:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {*} ctx 
 * @param {*} partialKey - Piece of key to serch
 */
async getAllStates(ctx, partialKey) {
  let result = await ctx.informedConsentFormStateList.getStatesFromPartialCompositeKey(partialKey);
  console.log('================ Result inside getAllStates method ================');
  console.log(result);
  return result;
} // fin func
```

Insinde informedConsentFormStateList.js:

````
```
async getStatesFromPartialCompositeKey(partialKey) {
        return this.getAllStatesFromPartialCompositeKey(partialKey);
    }
```
````

Inside the modified stateList.js:

```
/**
* @function getAllStatesFromPartialCompositeKey
*/
async getAllStatesFromPartialCompositeKey(partialArgument) {
  console.log('================ Called from beginning of getAllStatesFromPartialCompositeKey ================');
  console.log('================ name => ' + this.name);
  let key = this.ctx.stub.createCompositeKey(this.name, [partialArgument]);
  console.log('================ created partial key .....');
  console.log(partialArgument);
  console.log(key);
  let response = await this.ctx.stub.getStateByPartialCompositeKey(this.name, [key]); //.toString('utf8')
  console.log('================ response below ================');
  console.log(response);
  let results = await this.getAllResults(response);
  return results;
} // fin getAllStatesFromPartialCompositeKey
```

Here is how I invoke it:

```
/home/ubilab/fabric2/fabric-samples/test-network$ peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --channelID mychannel --name informed_consent_9 --tls true --cafile $ORDERER_CA --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles $ORG1_CA -c '{"Args":["csacmpcc:getAllStates","P03"]}'
```

Response:

```
chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> INFO 001 Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200 payload:"[]"
```

Chaincode container logs:

```
================ Called from beginning of getAllStatesFromPartialCompositeKey ================
================ name => org.csa.informedconsentformstatelist
================ created partial key .....
P03
org.csa.informedconsentformstatelistP03
================ Result inside getAllStates method ================
[]
```

Couchdb Stored state:

```
{
  "id": "\u0000org.csa.informedconsentformstatelist\u0000\"P03\"\u0000\"R68\"\u0000",
  "key": "\u0000org.csa.informedconsentformstatelist\u0000\"P03\"\u0000\"R68\"\u0000",
  "value": {
    "rev": "1-74db76a10ad8251ce2ba49ad58710ad8"
  },
  "doc": {
    "_id": "\u0000org.csa.informedconsentformstatelist\u0000\"P03\"\u0000\"R68\"\u0000",
    "_rev": "1-74db76a10ad8251ce2ba49ad58710ad8",
    "class": "org.csa.informedconsentform",
    "consentStatus": "1",
    "currentState": null,
    "key": "\"P03\":\"R68\"",
    "patientID": "P03",
    "reserachID": "R68",
    "sensors": "{numberOfSensors:1,sensors:[{sensorID:s01,name:SPO2,startDate:5/12/2020,endDate:5/12/2021}]}",
    "~version": "CgMBZQA="
  }
}
```

If you need more information to be able to help me please do not hesitate to ask :). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are querying with a single attribute, try using the *partialKey* variable directly instead of building a composite key.

```
let response = await this.ctx.stub.getStateByPartialCompositeKey(this.name, [partialKey]);
```

[API docs](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-node/master/api/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html#getStateByPartialCompositeKey__anchor)

Comment: Thank you for you help @Iaharris. Sorry it took so long! With your changes I was able to query the ledger using this command: ```peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile ${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem --channelID mychannel -n csa7 -c '{"Args":["csacmpcc:getAllStates","\"P03\""]}'```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to get a response would be to use an iterator :

```
  let allResults = [];
  let res = { done: false, value: null };
  let jsonRes = {};
  res= await ctx.stub.getStateByPartialCompositeKey(this.name, [partialKey]);
    

  

while (!res.done) {
  jsonRes.Key = res.value.key;

  try {
      jsonRes.Record = JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString('utf8'));
      allResults.push(jsonRes);
      res = await iterator.next();
    }
   catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return {}
  }
  
}
await iterator.close();
return allResults;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try this solution later!